# Bitbucket Cross Repository Issue

Tags: bitbucket

I am using GIT based platform working on different repository in Bitbucket. Suddenly using git, I accidentally fetch different branch from 
other repository — and it says that thousands of codes were fetch. The problem is - how will it affect on my current repository.

Do i need to revert / rollback it? How?
or if I check-out to master and pull the current updated branch, will it fix?

Hoping for your immediate response.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No worries. Checking-out on the master and pulling back the updated branch will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, do you think my current repo will not be affected?